# Generic type from keyof that is an object

Tags: typescript, object, generics, types, keyof

I'd like to type a generic function to only include values that are of type object (and ignore/disallow the other ones).

This is to only allow updating objects within a map.
Is it possible? I haven't been able to find a solution.

```
enum SKey {
  key1 = "key1",
  key2 = "key2",
}

type SItem = {
  [SKey.key1]: boolean;
  [SKey.key2]: {
    attr1: string;
    attr2: boolean;
  };
};

const mapDB: SItem = {
  [SKey.key1]: true,
  [SKey.key2]: {
    attr1: "hello",
    attr2: true,
  },
};

export function updateDbItem<K extends keyof SItem>(
  key: K,
  newFields: Partial<SItem[K]>
) {
  const item: SItem[K] = mapDB[key];
  mapDB[key] = { ...item, ...newFields };
}
```

But obviously I get the following error

```
error TS2698: Spread types may only be created from object types.

mapDB[key] = { ...item, ...newFields };
              ~~~~~~~~
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to derive a union of only the keys whose values are object types.

> In the code you've shown, this evaluates to only `SKey.key2`, but if you add more entries to `SItem`, then it will also include other keys that meet the criteria.

Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=36&pc=2#code/KYOwrgtgBAyg0sAnlA3gKClA1kgjFAXigCIdFdiAaDbJAJkJLLqrQF800AXRAB2FgBJLsGhF0mANrwkAOjK4AugC4oAIwD2GgDbAAhiADcNaQkTz6K1DUx6uXAE65VAZ0cBLEAHNjmW-Yc6VU0dfSMaNmNIzgBjDRA3KAg9XgARACFVGGFRRgkoUzkFK0cwYGopGXNmK3z-R2cSAAtgbW0NVj8oO0cgqFLyiOpo7j4BbJEIAHk1ACtgGK4zRjINADNrKRsoOChPWkR1oUnul2PRSThFKGAADxEQABMzgCUFjQdHgB43B08vShQMAgLAgDQAdxAAD5tpgAPw7WFQVQgYAAN2ADhoVmBoIh4RGd14Hy4UDWwMW7niQN4jzswFSahyEC+uzuD2e52mcwWSyQUIAFDQyKo4BUoKjwQAxdytZ6qAAKegcXHcem0XwmFyuMIAlJsoHEEqT3JMsszLtciMk0ulJGRFL4kikMvakFbUFBZN7TaJAd7ZJKZXKztEOEA)

```ts
type SItemObjectKey = keyof {
  [
    K in keyof SItem as SItem[K] extends Record<string, unknown>
      ? K
      : never
  ]: unknown;
};

export function updateDbItem<K extends SItemObjectKey>(
  key: K,
  newFields: Partial<SItem[K]>
) {
  const item: SItem[K] = mapDB[key];
  mapDB[key] = { ...item, ...newFields }; // Ok now!
}
```

See also: the utility type [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)

Comment: This is a beautiful solution, thanks! Unfortunately we're working with two versions of  TypeScript (3.5.3 and 3.8.2) and mapped types won't work. Any chance there is an alternative for older versions?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74808614/generic-type-from-keyof-that-is-an-object/74808723?noredirect=1#comment132025965_74808723) @ThomasGak-Deluen Wow — those are quite ancient versions of TypeScript! I definitely recommend updating. As far as a workaround: you can always just manually specify the object keys as a union — e.g. `type SItemObjectKey = SKey.key2 | SKey.key4 | SKey.key7;`

Comment: Thank you, we're working on it!